# Was-Relativsatz ohne zu attribuierendes Nomen

Tags: relative-clause

Ich habe auf einer [Webseite](https://deutschegrammatik20.de/attribute/relativsatz/relativsatz-was-wo/) gesehen, wie man den Relativsatz mit *was* benutzt:

> Nach unbestimmten Zahlwörtern, nach nominalisierten Superlativen und nach *das*, kann ein Relativsatz mit was stehen.

Ein Beispiel:

> "Das, was Peter gemacht hat, war nicht richtig."

Soweit alles gut. Heute bin ich aber beim Lesen eines Buchs auf diesen Satz gestoßen:

> "**was bei den Psychoneurosen für solches gehalten wird**, läßt sich allemal durch Einwirkung der Zensur auf eine Gedankenreihe aufklären, welche von verborgen gebliebenen Zielvorstellungen in den Vordergrund geschoben wird." (Auch [hier](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/freud/traumdeu/chap007.html) zu lesen.)

Vor dem fett markierten Relativsatz steht aber kein Nomen. Ich glaube, wenn ich die Erklärung der oben genannten Webseite ernst nehme, könnte ich den Satz so umschreiben:

> "**Das, was bei den Psychoneurosen für solches gehalten wird**, läßt sich allemal durch Einwirkung der Zensur auf eine Gedankenreihe aufklären, …"

Aber im eigentlichen Satz steht kein *Das* vor dem Relativsatz. Ich nahm an, dass dieser Relativsatz das Subjekt vom folgenden Teil ("… läßt sich allemal…") ist oder wenigstens die Funktion des Subjektes übernimmt. Stimmt das? (Frage 1)

Wenn ja, heißt das, dass ein Was-Relativsatz bzw. ein Wo+Präposition-Relativsatz manchmal ein Nomen ersetzen kann? (Frage 2) Ich habe nämlich noch einen anderen Satz in demselben Buch gefunden, der meinem Verständnis nach danach aussah:

> "Die Delirien sind das Werk einer Zensur, die sich keine Mühe mehr gibt, ihr Walten zu verbergen, die anstatt ihre Mitwirkung zu einer nicht mehr anstößigen Umarbeitung zu leihen, rücksichtslos ausstreicht, **wogegen sie Einspruch erhebt**, wodurch dann das Übriggelassene zusammenhanglos wird."

Ich glaube, dass der fett markierte Relativsatz als Objekt des Verbs "ausstreichen" fungiert. Stimmt das? (Frage 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zur Frage 1:

> Ich nahm an, dass dieser Relativsatz das Subjekt vom folgenden Teil ist oder wenigstens die Funktion des Subjektes übernimmt.

Ja, das ist korrekt. Das (weggelassene) "das" erfüllt lediglich die Aufgabe, als Bezugspunkt für den Relativsatz zu dienen, sozusagen *das, was im Relativsatz ausführlicher aufgeführt wird*, zusammenzufassen. (Wie man hier sieht, kann der Relativsatz nicht nur das Subjekt vertreten, sondern auch ein Objekt.)

Das "das" kann übrigens nicht nur vor, sondern auch nach dem Relativsatz stehen, auf den es sich bezieht. *Was dann im Relativsatz steht, **das*** wird dann zusammengefaßt.

Immer aber ist dieses "das" optional. Verwendet wird es, um einerseits anzuzeigen, welcher Teil genau durch den Relativsatz ersetzt bzw. erweitert wird, andererseits zur Verstärkung oder Betonung:

> Die hinweisende Wirkung des Relativsatzes zu verstärken, **das** ist die Aufgabe des "das" im Hauptsatz!

Zur Frage 2 (und auch 3):

> Wenn ja, heißt das, dass Was-Relativsatz bzw. wo+Präposition-Relativsatz manchmal ein Nomen ersetzen kann?

Ja, genau das heißt das. Das ist sogar seine ureigentliche Aufgabe, nämlich Dinge auszudrücken, die durch ein (einzelnes) Nomen nicht beschrieben werden können. zum Beispiel:

> Ich nehme einen Teil.
> Ich nehme (das), was ich mir nehmen kann ohne daß es weiter auffällt.

In der Struktur des Satzes erfüllen sowohl "einen Teil" wie der Relativsatz (bzw. das "das" im Hauptsatz, das als dessen Bezugspunkt dient) die Rolle des Akkusativobjekts.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die ausführliche Erklärung!

Answer (score 2):

Ergänzung:

Satzteile wie dieses "Das" im Ausgangsbeispiel werden in der Grammatik "**Korrelate**" genannt. Korrelate verweisen auf Satzglieder (Subjekt, Objekt ...), die die Form bzw. Funktion eines Nebensatzes haben. Oft sind Korrelate fakultativ weglassbar, manchmal obligatorisch-vorhanden, manchmal obligatorisch nicht-vorhanden. Bei den fakultativ-weglassbaren gibt es oft Tendenzen dafür (= mit Korrelat) oder dagegen (= ohne Korrelat). Die weglassbaren erscheinen redundant, aber für mich verbessern sie oft die Verständlichkeit, weil sie die syntaktische Struktur sichtbarer machen.

Beispiele:

*Sie weiß, **was** sie will*. - obligatorisch ohne Korrelat

***Über das**, was sie wirklich will, hat sie mit niemandem gesprochen.* - obligatorisch mit Korrelat

***Das**, was du sagst, ist nicht die ganze Wahrheit.* - fakultativ weglassbar

Zu Frage 1: Das "das" vor dem *was*-Relativsatz ist kein Nomen, sondern ein Pronomen. Als Korrelate kommen nur Pronomen oder funktionsähnliche Ausdrücke in Frage.

Zu Frage 2: Richtig erkannt: Der *was*-Relativsatz "ersetzt" nicht das Subjekt, sondern er **ist** das Subjekt.

Zu Frage 3: Ja, der *wogegen*-Satz ist das Akkusativobjekt. Hier hätte ich mir allerdings ein Korrelat gewünscht: "*... rücksichtslos **alles** ausstreicht, wogegen sie Einspruch erhebt*", bzw. in anderer Formulierung "*... rücksichtslos alles ausstreicht, gegen das sie Einspruch erhebt*". "*Wogegen*" wird meinem Eindruck nach heute anders verwendet [*Dieses Mal soll es zum Urlaub in die Berge gehen, wogegen wundersamerweise niemand aus der Familie etwas hat*.]

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Ergänzung! Es hilft mir sehr.

Comment: Gibt es eine Methode, durch die ich es erkennen kann, ob ein Satz obligatorisch ohne Korrelat sein muss?

Comment: Ich kenne erst einmal keine. Ich vermute, sie sind Teil der Valenzen des Verbs. Ebenso, wie man lernen muss, mit welchen Objekten, Nebensatzformen und sonstigen Ergänzungen sich ein Verb verbinden kann, muss man gegebenenfalls lernen, ob nebensatzförmige Ergänzungen ein Korrelat haben können oder müssen. Solche Valenzkataloge pro Verb sind sehr umfangreich, die Wörterbücher geben davon nur einen winzigen Ausschnitt wieder. [Hier](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/verbvalenz) kann man solche Informationen zu einzelnen Verben über die Alphabetliste ansteuern und abfragen.

Answer (score 1):

Dieses *das* wird gerne weggelassen. Schreibt man es hin, betont man es besonders. Varianten mit noch stärkerer Betonung sind *genau das*, *eben das* oder *all das*.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Antwort!